# Expand and collapse post reputation in the whole range of the row

Tags: bug, reputation

### Steps to reproduce:

Go to anyone's [post reputation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama?tab=reputation&sort=post). There try to hover the daily reputation summary row, let's say in the middle of the row (like shown on the screenshot) and try to click. I would naturally expect that the row will expand, but nothing happens. The same happens for collapsing.

To expand or collapse rows there, you must click the arrows on the left, which would be fine in my view, but the cursor is quite misleading then.

[image]

### Question:

Could you allow us to expand and collapse the daily reputation summary rows by clicking anywhere on the row ? Or if not, could you at least change the cursor to a default arrow ?

Comment: Please don't edit (poke) [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/208810/4) to get attention to your question. The correct way is to start [a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)!

Comment: @hims056, ok, I've set a bounty and guess what. My poke edits received much more views than this bounty... Well, it was at Christmas time in many countries, but still. Ok, I'll set a bounty once again in January and if that won't help, guess what I'll do until I reach at least 100 views or someone ban me :-) And don't you worry, I know how SE works quite enough to know that I should have set bounty, but tell me, who cares about this "cheating" on meta ? I'm trying to improve something here. I wouldn't do this on non-meta sites...